# How to post to Facebook fanpage as fanpage, not user

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

How can I post on fanpage wall as fanpage not as a user - using javascript sdk.

RIght now on Init im receiving menage_pages and acquiring suitable fanpage id, how can i change call below?

```
var target = '/'+params.target+'/feed'

FB.api(target,
        'post',
        { message: params.message,
          link: params.link,
          picture: params.picture,
          caption: params.caption,
          description: params.description,
          name: params.name
          }
        ,function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                $("#error").removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $("#success").removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the following permissions:

- `publish_stream`
- `manage_pages`

Now we call the `page` object to retrieve the page's `access_token` and then post with that token, something like:

```
function postToPage() {
    var page_id = 'MY_PAGE_ID';
    FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
        if(resp.access_token) {
            FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
                'post',
                { message: "I'm a Page!", access_token: resp.access_token }
                ,function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Result:
[image]

More about this in my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/).

Comment: i am trying `postToPage()` js function but no response console.log().
onclick like..
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='postToPage(); return false;'>Post to Group</a>

Comment: Your first question, this call is actually getting the `access_token` and here you are asking Facebook to get that field for you! You just need to edit the `page_id`.

Comment: For your second comment, the session might be expired by the time you have called `postToPage()`, so you need to implement [`FB.getLoginStatus()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/).

Comment: yes i replace page_id with `5236..` but can't success..if i write console.log(resp) - return page id.

Comment: I have try FB.getLoginStatus() . it return `not_authorized`.

Comment: Are you actually reading the `FB.getLoginStatus()` documentation? You first need to be the admin of the page, then you need to authorize the app for it to be able to get the page access token

Comment: @ifaour, for message post alone it work.. if you add picture, link {it won't work}. then it won't... In case if user want to return to my page how could i do??

Answer (score 0):

All you need is those three functionalities to be implemented:

First one is for setting the basic parameters for your Application(XXX-APP needs to be changed with your real id of application).

Second, function fol login to Facebook and granting needed permissions to be able to post to Facebook.

Third function is for posting to Facebook(XXX-page need to be changed with ID of the Page that you want to post something)

```
FB.init({ appId: 'XXX-APP', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
access_token = '';
function loginFB(){
  FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
     console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'publish_stream,manage_pages'});
}

function postToPage() {
    FB.api('/XXX-page', {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
        if(resp.access_token) {
            FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
                'post',
                { message: "MSG", access_token: resp.access_token }
                ,function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
}
```