# Posting a Photo to my Facebook Wall (working) But posts to the User Feed

Tags: php, facebook

Ok, this all works fine... EXCEPT, the photo posts to the User Feed, instead of posting as the page admin... (it posts from my personal Facebook account, instead of as the page)

Searched all over for an answer, but coming up empty...

(config.php)

```
<?PHP

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appId,
  'secret' => $appSecret,
'fileUpload' => true,
'cookie' => true  
));

$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

?>

<?php
include_once("config.php");
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$userPageId = 619143434781602;

if ($fbuser) {
        try {

        $img = $imgSrc;
        $post_url = '/'.$userPageId.'/photos';

        $photo = $facebook->api($post_url, 'POST',
        array(
                'source' => '@' . 'test.jpg',
                'message' => 'Photo uploaded via the PHP SDK!'
        )
);

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
          }

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a way you can do it by using js if you take a look at [How to post to Facebook fanpage as fanpage, not user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034753/how-to-post-to-facebook-fanpage-as-fanpage-not-user)

this may also give you an insight http://www.sergiy.ca/post-on-facebook-app-wall-and-fan-page-wall-as-admin/

happy reading and good luck

Comment: this does not talk about posting photos, but thanks. i can post to the feed fine, if it's just text, but the trouble i am having is posting to the facebook page feed as the page, when posting a photo.

Comment: ah okay, my bad, i mis read, i thought you were just having trouble posting all together, and that the wrong profile picture was being posted. i will have a look and get back